# Visual Studio 2022 Enable Web Live Preview

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I wanted to try developing a website in VS but I'd really like a visual (WYSIWYG) editor. [Apparently, this is available in VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/visual-studio-toolbox/web-live-preview). In that video, and lots of other videos and websites, it shows 'Design' and 'Split' buttons on the window, which should show a live view of the web page that's open. It seems this is supposed to work with both .aspx and .cshtml files.

However, nowhere can I find how to enable this, and I've done a lot of searching. I've even uninstalled and reinstalled VS. There are no options, settings or menu options to enable it. I'm using VS 2022 Community, fully up to date, in an ASP.NET Core Web App project using .NET 7.0.

Does anyone know what's wrong? I wondered if it was only available in VS Professional/Enterprise, but seemed silly to me.

Comment: You're not going to be able to find a visual editor that renders identical to what you would see in a browser. It's just not really feasible. Even in Visual Studio's WPF and WinForms editors, the window sizes aren't exact so you may get some controls going out of the window even if they don't in the editor if you use exact positions. With websites it's even more of a problem because of different screen resolutions. The page you linked mentions that the preview is specifically for *"building Web Forms projects"*. So if your project isn't Web Forms, you probably won't be able to use it.

Comment: Not true at all. It uses the latest chrome engine - so it darn amazing. However, the poster is using .net core, and VERY likely using MVC and not web forms. So, that cool great new feature (one the BEST new features in vs2022) is ONLY for web forms!! (so much for webforms being dead then, right!!!!). so, this feature is NOT for .net core, and NOT for MVC, but for webforms, and .net framework only.

Comment: See my post below for some screen caps of the designers say vs viewing in a browser.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Correct but the way the question is worded (especially the first line) seems to imply the OP is asking about a visual editor, not just a preview. That's what I was talking about and why I specified *"visual editor"*.

Comment: Sure, that's fair. I mean, quite sure webforms was the only setup that offered a visual designer. However, think often most will just keep the browser open, make some changes, ctrl-s and then refresh the browser. This much explains probably why most don't miss the webforms setup anyway.

Comment: I have the same question as the OP, and we ARE using ASP.NET WebForms.  Still, the "Design" window in my copy of VS2022 looks just the way it did ten years ago, and I also don't know how to ENABLE Web Live Preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that feature in the brand new vs2022 is for ONLY .net framework, and ONLY for web forms.

So, if you using MVC, then you don't have a forms designer.

And if you using .net core, then you can't use this feature either.

So, when you create a project, it MUST be .net framework (not .net core), and it MUST be a webforms project, and NOT MVC projects.

So, that would be say this (for c#).

[image]

And (best choice) would of course be this template:

[image]

And if using vb.net, then again, same thing:

So, web projects, and .net framework - NOT .net core projects.

thus:

[image]

So, out of those templates, then again, of course a asp.net web application would be the preferred choice.

so, for example, here is a gridview in "live" preview, and yes you can edit or drag + drop controls into that live preview.

it looks like this (split screen for example).

[image]

but, if I run the page, same in a chrome based browser (Edge, or chrome).

Then I see this:

[image]

Since the new designer is based on the chrome engine then as above shows, yes, it is rather cool.

Here is that web page, not split view in the designer:
(so I have NOT yet hit f5 to run, but only am in design mode)

[image]

so, in old legacy designer, I would see/get this:

[image]

So, note how do you DO NOT see say for example the bootstrap menu bar.

But, if I turn on live preview, and now I see/get this:

[image]

Note how we now even see the bootstrap menu bar in the preview - I have not yet hit f5 to run in browser. And on the bottom, you see a "bread-crumb hierarchy" as to what element you clicked on (very much like f12 debug tools in a browser, and then using "elements" selection).

Comment: Well that answers that! Seems a bit pointless to put all that effort into providing a feature for a legacy .net version and give us nothing if we want to use the latest one. Never mind, I'll find something to build my website with. Thanks!

Comment: Well, the later versions of such systems never had a visual designer, and like everyone else, you type in markup - kind of how everyone else works. but then again, this does show why people liked webforms so much - it was easy, and for starting out with a visual designer is REALLY nice, and now the new one is on steroids and even better. So, web forms is a drag + drop, and event driven setup that works like desktop software. Most today thus don't want that kind of setup, but it is beyond easy to get going with, and toss in react, jQuery, or any other framework into web forms is killer setup

Comment: I suspect that hunting down a nice template, then attacking it in an HTML editor to fit my branding (I'm using BlueGriffon now) will work fine for me. I don't need anything flashy - just who are we and what does our business do sort of stuff - there are plenty of basic online templates that do that.

Comment: Sure, today I don't think (or know) if people want a web based GUI designer. All of the up and comming folks as noted use a simple editor for their markups, hit ctrl-s to save, and hten re-fresh their browsers. However, I STILL VERY much like the idea of a GUI at design time to get a basic web page laid out. Adding style,css etc. can come later, but the fact that webforms has a GUI web based designers? It is rather nice. So, this issue is not about templates, it about a GUI based drag and drop design. As I stated, to get this type of experience, you have to create/use webforms.

Comment: I agree. It would be nice to have a drag and drop editor. Anyway I've actually picked out a nice template as it does save me an awful lot of coding faff, and now have it open on one screen whilst editing the code in BlueGriffon on another. Editing the CSS is a bit of a faff but it's working out for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can find it by creating an asp.net web (.Net Framework) and selecting Web Form in it.

I use vs2022 17.4.2 community version

[image]

You can also view its settings in the tool.

[image]

Comment: That preview in designer is the older "legacy" designer. See my last screen shot below - you note how the bootstrap menu bar now renders.